# Fresh ubuntu system, after login black screen flashing

Tags: ubuntu, black-screen-of-death

I wanted to change my Windows 10 for ubuntu. I have deleted whole windows. After instalation I was told to reboot my computer, so I did it. My login screen is black, when I write correct password screen changed to another black window and I am back again in login screen. I have gtx 1060.

Comment: Reinstall from start.

Comment: Can you press Ctrl-Alt-F# (substitute # with 1-7) and get to a black screen with text on it? If you can, then it’s a problem with the login manager

Comment: Use `nomodeset` to boot in low graphics mode and then install the recommended Nvidia drivers. How to do one and the other are covered here and AskUbuntu in many questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks, will keep it in mind. I reinstaled Ubuntu, just after instalation installed drivers and instead od rebooting I turned off and on PC.